# "bash: aws: command not found" on Windows 7 in Git Bash

Tags: path, aws-cli, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to use AWS CLI to access CodeCommit.  And it's sort of working.  I am able to use the aws command in the Windows command prompt.  However, when I try to access it using the Git Bash shell, it says

> "bash: aws: command not found."

Additionally, when I try to do do a git clone in the Windows command promt, trying to access CodeCommit, it tries to use aws using the credentials helper, which also results in "aws: command not found."

[image]

I followed the instructions in the AWS documentation, which suggests some directories to add to the PATH:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html#awscli-install-windows-path

Here's what my PATH variable looks like:

> C:\Users\ddrayton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\ddrayton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Windows\System32;;C:\Program
>   Files\Docker
>   Toolbox;C:\Users\ddrayton\MyCurl;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts;C:\Program
>   Files\Amazon\AWSCLI;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Amazon\AWSCLI;C:\Users\ddrayton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Users\ddrayton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts

But I'm not sure if it's a PATH problem, since the Windows command prompt has no problem accessing the "aws" command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed this by simply installing the AWS CLI *again* but this time using Git Bash instead of the Windows command prompt.

> pip install awscli

If anyone could provide some insight as to why this was necessary, it would be appreciated.

Comment: This helped me. In my situation i even did not have pip installed. So I had to install Pithon, then use the pip command above.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I should note that although this solution fixed my problem on one computer, it did NOT fix my problem on my other computer. :-(

Comment: It worked for me, i also faced same problem, aws command was working fine in command prompt but not in git bash.

Comment: I didn't have to run `pip install awscli` I simply installed awscli via the windows UI installer and then restarted my code editor and terminal and it worked

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I think a recent-to-me update to the AWS CLI changed what's run to being `aws.cmd` (full path `C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws.cmd`)

Git Bash needs the extension `aws.cmd` to make it work.

In Bash, you could try typing `aws.cmd` vs `aws`. If the former works, but not the latter, you can do `alias aws='aws.cmd'` in your bash startup script. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it worked for me.

FWIW, I think it's related to this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280528/is-there-a-unix-equivalent-of-the-windows-environment-variable-pathext

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I was installing just once from GitBash via `pip install awscli --upgrade --user` as described in AWS manual for CLI installation for [Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html#install-linux-awscli)

It installed **aws** executables into `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

After that just add this folder to your PATH. Re-open GitBash or cmd - it should work from both places